# PHP: SOAP response sort results

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to sort the results by ROOMPRICE of a soap response :

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [GetHotelsResult] => stdClass Object ( 
        [SEARCH_RESPONSE] => Array ( 
            [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                [HOTELNAME] => Hotel1 
                [ROOMNAME] => Room2 
                [ROOMPRICE] => 144.50 
            ) 
            [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                [HOTELNAME] => Hotel1 
                [ROOMNAME] => Room1 
                [ROOMPRICE] => 231.10 
            ) 
            [2] => stdClass Object ( 
                [HOTELNAME] => Hotel1 
                [ROOMNAME] => Room3 
                [ROOMPRICE] => 94.00 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
);
```

I've made many solutions, but they didn't work...

MY ACTUAL CODE:

```
$sClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
$response = $sClient->GetHotels($data);     
$ghdata = $sClient->__getLastResponse();
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($ghdata); 
$x = $doc->documentElement;
$rooms = $x->getElementsByTagName( "SEARCH_RESPONSE" );
    foreach( $rooms as $SEARCH_RESPONSE )
{ // show results
```

Comment: It seems like there is an error or typo in your response: `SEARCH_RESPONSE ` array cannot have there records with `0` index each.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$response` is your outer `stdClass` object, I guess you're getting and error like that:

```
Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in ...
```

This is because `usort` works with array and not objects. What you actually want to sort is a `SEARCH_RESPONSE` array. Also, pay attention that elements in this array are `stdClass` objects themselves, so you have to use `$a->{$key}` notation instead of `[]`:

```
function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        // pay attention to `{$key}` notation
        return strnatcmp($a->{$key}, $b->{$key});
   };
}

// Get array to sort
usort($response->GetHotelsResult->SEARCH_RESPONSE, build_sorter('ROOMPRICE'));

foreach ($response->GetHotelsResult->SEARCH_RESPONSE as $item) {
    echo $item->ROOMNAME . ', ' . $item->ROOMPRICE . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Nice! It worked seperatly, but i'm trying to put in my code. Ican't figure out how. (question updated to put a sample of my actual code)